# What is the right way of state holding in JetpackCompose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a question about 2 ways of Compose State Holding.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val viewModel by viewModels<MyViewModel>()
            MyExampleTheme {
                val analyticsOnly by viewModel.analyticsOnly.collectAsState()
                ComposeStateHoldingMethod1(analyticsOnly, viewModel::onAnalyticsOnlyChanged)
                ComposeStateHoldingMethod2(viewModel::onAnalyticsOnlyChanged)
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    private fun ComposeStateHoldingMethod1(
        analyticsOnly: Boolean,
        onAnalyticsOnlyValueChanged: (Boolean) -> Unit
    ) {
        Switch(checked = analyticsOnly, onCheckedChange = onAnalyticsOnlyValueChanged)
    }

    @Composable
    private fun ComposeStateHoldingMethod2(
        onAnalyticsOnlyValueChanged: (Boolean) -> Unit
    ) {
        var analyticsOnly by remember {
            mutableStateOf(false)
        }
        Switch(checked = analyticsOnly, onCheckedChange = {
            analyticsOnly = it
            onAnalyticsOnlyValueChanged(it)
        })
    }
}
```

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {
    private val _analyticsOnly = MutableStateFlow(false)
    val analyticsOnly = _analyticsOnly.asStateFlow()

    fun onAnalyticsOnlyChanged(analyticsOnly: Boolean) {
        _analyticsOnly.value = analyticsOnly
    }
}
```

In the code blocks that i attached above, you will see 2 ways of Compose State holding.

Method 1:
Storing all of states in ViewModel, change it from ViewModel and notify the Composable with collected state from ViewModel(The stateles composable pattern, but I have to pass more parameters  to Composable).

Method 2:
Storing the ui state in the composable and just passing the event to ViewModel to doing some logical work.

I know the Compose documentation’s recommends, pass the events to the the highest possible Composable, and store states in the lowest possible place, but I'm still confusing about these approaches, because both of them has own downside and benefits. Which one is better or right?

Comment: What are the pros and cons according to you? What is your use case?